# How to display a list of posts in a list of categories in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am looking for my web page to display a list of categories and a list of each post within the category.

For example:

[image: What i want to achieve]

However, it is looping through and displaying each category and associated post separately, like this:

[image: whats actually happening]

Here is Template:

```
<ul>
  {% for p in object_list %}          
  <li>
    {{p.category.name}}
    <ul>
      <li>
        {{p.title}}
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category', null=False)
```

Views

```
class CategoryList(ListView):
    template_name = 'category_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all().select_related('category')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your template code to this

```html
{% regroup object_list by category as post_list %}

<ul>
    {% for post_category in post_list %}
        <li>{{ post_category.grouper }}
            <ul>
            {% for post in post_category.list %}
                <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
views.py:

```
def get_queryset(request):
    categorys = {category: Post.objects.filter(category = category) for category in Category.objects.all()}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  {% for category, posts in categorys.items %}
    <li>
      {{category.name}}
      {% for comment in comments %}
        <ul>
          <li>
            {{posts.title}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      {% endfor %}
    <li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Use 2-layer nested loops to display posts and categories, each item in the outer loop is a category, and each item category in the inner loop is the title of the posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the template with regroup. Also order the items to be grouped by the field you wish to group with.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup