# How to add Wagtail blog categories as links in header and footer

Tags: django, wagtail

I am building simple blog with posts and posts categories.
I would like to add links to posts categories to header and footer, so they appear on every page, not just home page (as routable pages).
How do I go about it?

Category class as below:

```
class BlogCategory(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField( # field name has to be 'title'
    verbose_name='Name', max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField( populate_from='title', editable=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel("title"),
            FieldPanel("slug"),
        ], heading="New Category"),]

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Code for routable page:

```
class BlogIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
  class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Index Page"

  template = "blog/blog_index_page.html"
  parent_page_types = ["wagtailcore.Page"]
  subpage_types = ["blog.PostArticlePage"]
  max_count = 1

  # context ------------------------------
  def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

    all_posts = (
        BlogDetailPage.objects.live().public().order_by("-first_published_at")
    )

    context["posts"] = all_posts

  @route(r"^category/(?P<cat_slug>[-\w]*)/$", name="category_view")
  def category_view(self, request, cat_slug):
    context = self.get_context(request)
    try:
        category = BlogCategory.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)
    except Exception:
        return redirect(self.url)

    if category is None:
        return redirect('/')

    context["posts"] = (BlogDetailPage.objects.live().public().filter(categories__in=[category]))
    return render(request, "blog/blog_view_page.html", context)
```

Comment: Did you try creating a new view and then filter by category?

Comment: Do you mean hard code a new view for each category and then add it to menu bar as a link? No. I managed to create a template tag that fetches latest posts but it wont appear in a header. I believe blog categories have to be added to global context just I dont know how.

Comment: No, I meant something else but then I thought somebody must've asked this before and came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709138/how-to-display-a-list-of-posts-in-a-list-of-categories-in-django I think it should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

To add blog categories to header and footer:

First create a simple template tag

```
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag()
def get_categories():
  return BlogCategory.objects.all()
```

Next add following code to header and footer

```
{% load blog_tags %}
{% get_categories as categories %}

<nav>
  <ul>
    {% for cat in categories %}
    <li><a href="category/{{ cat.slug }}">{{ cat.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Finally, reload the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709138/how-to-display-a-list-of-posts-in-a-list-of-categories-in-django) :

```
{% regroup object_list by category as post_list %}
<ul>
    {% for post_category in post_list %}
        <li>{{ post_category.grouper }}
        <ul>
        {% for post in post_category.list %}
            <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

You may have to modify it a bit but the principal is the same.

The regroup tag is well explained in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/) and Wagtail docs clearly mention they support Django tags.

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to regroup my posts, I just want to add category names to navigation bar in header and footer. I believe I need to add categories to global context processor somehow.

Comment: @GeoMeteoMe Can you include the respective sections of your code such as models, views and templates? I have a feeling you're overthinking this.